# How to create mongoDB index on a field referred to document id from another collection

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, asynchronous, indexing

Currently developing an Angular site in order to train myself on various domains, I have several questions about database queries.

To summarize the structure of my mongoDB database, I have 2 collections :

- One of customers, which contains the information of the different customers of my system.
- An animal one, which contains the information of the animals. In addition to this, each animal has a "customer" field with the value of the document id that represents its master.

[image]

I know I could have directly put the animal documents as attributes of the customer documents, but I preferred to do it like this for the first time.

My question is about the following request:

```
exports.getbyCustomer = (req, res, next) => {
    Animal.find({customer: req.params.id}).collation({locale: "en" }).sort({'name': 1})
    .then(animals => res.status(200).send(animals))
    .catch(error => res.status(400).send({ error: error.message }));
}
```

When I make this request, will MongoDB "stupidly" iterate on each document of the animal collection and compare the id passed in parameter with the one of the current document? If there is a match, mongo keep it for a future return?

If it is the case, can the indexes improve this behavior? I had read that indexes allow to set up a binary tree in order to speed up the database processing (not relating to MongoDB in particular). **Is there a way to do this with MongoDB ?**

[image]

By quickly reading the mongoDB documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#create-an-index

I created an index for the animal collection by simply putting "customer": 1 but I doubt it will do what I illustrated in the previous picture.

Comment: Why do you doubt that?

Comment: From what I've read, putting "customer: 1" will sort the documents in the ascending order of the field as visible here (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/_images/index-ascending.bakedsvg.svg)

Taking the context of the image, if I make a getByScore by passing, for example 30, will mongo automatically "set aside" documents with a lower score?

Comment: It is probably more useful in practice to think about which documents will be returned than which would be "set aside" (whatever you mean by that). Having an index allows the database to quickly jump to the first document that satisfies the criteria condition. From there the documents could start being returned to application or consumed internally for further processing (e.g. aggregation pipeline, etc.)

Comment: Ok, if I understood well, the fact of having put "customer":1 in my indexes for the collection "animals" will allow Mongo, when I pass as argument of the find method, {customer: 5eb3...},  to go directly to the first document having for the field "customer" the value 5eb3... and thus save time?

Comment: Yes, this a reasonable way of thinking about it I would say.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your explanation & time !

Comment: Note that collation matters.  If you specify a collation with your find query, only an index with the same collation will be considered to process the query.

Comment: Oh !

great info here Joe, thanks for that precious one !

Did the sort one must also be added ?

Comment: @Quentin __"Ok, if I understood well, the fact of having put "customer":1 in my indexes for the collection "animals" will allow Mongo, ... and thus save time?"_: You are querying the `animals` collection using the `customer`. Having an index on the `customer` field (of the `animal` collection) is to get the `animals` collection documents with that `customer` - quickly (it will be fast query). The result will be multiple `animals` documents. Also, note that the _sort_ operations use indexes too (for very fast sorting).

Comment: @prasad_ Did I must add the sort part into the index too to make a "mutliple field" index ?

Comment: See this: [Use Indexes to sort Query Results](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/index.html). See the sub-topics **Sort and Index Prefix** and **Sort and non-prefix subset of Index**.